# Какова скорость добавления формы ввода gui в языках программирования(используя лучшую среду разработки языка)?

Tags: ide, gui

Скорость добавления формы:

- добавление нового поля для ввода текста в программу, в конкретное место.(html - input) Мышкой двигать или надо лезть в код, добавлять функции с 20 параметрами. Создание шаблонов форм, чтобы затем сразу добавлять этот шаблон, с одинаковым функционалом(например поле ввода текста длиной до 20 символов где только буквы и цифры разрешены).
- Добавление стиля для этой формы(если это обязательно).
- Авто валидация формы(вывод сообщения, что что то неправильно введено, например формат телефона, email неправильный), указание через среду разработки мин-макс значений сразу при создании, удаление неправильных данных например спецсимволов, которые могут портить запросы к БД.
- чтение, запись, редактирование, удаление данных этого поля в-из СУБД.
- добавление кнопок(добавить, изменить, удалить).
- добавление обработчиков для кнопок по редактированию, добавлению, удалению записи этого поля.
- Дальнейшая работа с формой, возможность быстрого внесения изменений в неё.

Например на этом языке общее время для добавления новой формы, добавления обработчиков событий, добавления sql команд через функции и методы языка(доп библиотеки), чтения данных в БД, будет допустим занимать столько то времени.

```
 С++ - 17 часов.
 PHP + javascript + html - 45 мин.
 Си шарп - ? мин
 Java - ? мин
 Дельфи - ? мин
```

Например если надо сделать программу где будет 250 различных форм ввода, 
то можно грубо рассчитать, что делать её на С++, будет очень долго.

```
С++ ~4250 часов
PHP ~187 часов
Си шарп ~? часов
Java ~? часов
Дельфи ~? часов
```

Можете вписать примерные цифры вместо знаков вопросов, добавив языки и среды разработки которые могут сильно снизить время подобной разработки?

Comment: Вопрос не имеет смысла, т.к. все зависит от используемых технологий/фреймворков/велосипедов, а не от языка как такового. Да и вряд ли у кого-то есть конкретные цифры.

Comment: И вопросы-опросники запрещены, такие дела.

Comment: Ну так я написал, что можно добавить ide, фреймворк в список. 
Там может выйти что на С++ с visual studio можно сначала написать сценарий для формы, где уже будут все обработчики повешены, валидация задана и.т.д и выйдет всё гораздо быстрее чем на PHP с jquery делать.

Comment: Я кажется знаю как переформулировать вопрос, чтобы он заимел смысл: **с помощью чего быстрее всего создать gui форму?**